# PowerShell - Show Property of Parent Object and Child Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

If I have a list of email metadata in a hashtable and each email has a hashtable with a list of attachments inside that object, like this:

```
$Emails = @{     
            ID          = "E123"; 
            Subject     = "Check this out"; 
            Attachments = @{
                            ID   = "A123"; 
                            Name = "FunnyPic.jpg"
                           }
           }
```

And then that hashtable is converted to a PSObject like this:

```
$EmailsObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Emails
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
$EmailsObject | Select ID, Attachments.ID
```

How would I do that?

I want to associate the `ID` of the Email with the `ID`'s of the associated attachments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use calulated properties.

```
$Emails | Select-Object -Property @{Name='ID';Expression={$_.ID};},@{Name='AttachmentId';Expression={$_.Attachments.ID};}
```

You can shorten `Name` and `Expression` to `n` and `e`.

[See this article for more](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx).

Comment: You can reduce `@{Name='ID';Expression={$_.ID};}` to just `ID` :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that's true for a `PSCustomObject`, but OP is using a `HashTable` and the keys are not properties. `$Emails | select ID` will return a `PSCustomObject` with the property `ID` that is `$null`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a calculated property if you use `Select-Object`. something like this ...

```
$Emails = @{     
            ID          = "E123"; 
            Subject     = "Check this out"; 
            Attachments = @{
                            ID   = "A123"; 
                            Name = "FunnyPic.jpg"
                           }
           }
$EmailsObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Emails

$EmailsObject |
    Select-Object ID,
        @{
        n = 'AttID'
        e = {$_.Attachments.ID}
        }
```

output ...

```
ID   AttID
--   -----
E123 A123
```